# Keep window in front of another window (not on top) in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, interop

In Windows, is there a fairly reliable way to keep a window in front of another window?

The window in question would ideally always have a z-order of one greater than its target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Owner window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx).

```
new FormToolbar().Show(this);  // shows the toolbar on top of this window.
```

(when `this` is the form that should remain 1 behind the toolbar window.